# Django intermediary model

Tags: python, django

I dont understand Django Intermediary models at all. Let's say that i want to add one more additional field to User model, and store relationship between two users in another model(intermediary) like this:

```
class Contact(models.Model):
user_from = models.ForeignKey(User...)
user_to = models.ForeignKey(User...)
...
```

And the field i want to add is:

```
following = models.ManyToManyField('self',
    through=Contact,
    related_name='followers',
    symetrical=False)
```

What really happen when i call user_object.followers.all() and what is the difference between user_object.following.all() are they both the same?

Comment: They both return querysets of user_objects, but those querysets are not the same. Your naming may be a bit off: if you change "followers" to "followed_by", it may be clearer (i.e., a user may be following several other users, and each of these users will have a set of yet different users that they are followed by).

Comment: The simple thing to do is to create some users, add some followers ('following'), then print the various relations, and fiddle around with adding or removing users & followers until you see the picture.